# Check if Adsense javascript file response is 403 in the current page

Tags: javascript, php

I have some pages on my site that banned from Adsense and I need to auto check if that page successfully loaded Adsense JS file or it response
with 403 code.

If I check http status for https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js , It get 200, but I need to check it inside my page, its loaded and have 200 or it have 403.